# Play an .ogg audio stream in swift

Tags: swift, streaming, media-player, ogg

I tried to compile my .ogg audio stream without success, I compiled several frameworks and libraries without success... today May 2022, is there a way to play an .ogg url?

failure: AVPlayer, MobileVLCKit, StreamingKit, OGGDecode, IDZAQAudioPlayer, APAudioPlayer